# Python Index Error on 2.7.6 version

Tags: python, python-2.7, sandbox

When I run my code in python version 3 it works fine but when I run in python 2.7.6 sandbox I get an index error always.

The portion of the code that throws index error is:

```
 def matrix_multiply(A,B):
    result = [[0 for i in range(len(B[0]))] for i in range(len(A))]
    for i in range(len(A)):
       for j in range(len(B[0])):
          for k in range(len(B)):
             result[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j]
    return result[0]  #This throws index error
```

A and B are multidimensional lists representing matrices. Could you please help me resolve this issue thanks.:)

Comment: put `print result` right before your return statement and see what it says

Comment: Could you provide a sample input that triggers the error?

Comment: just curious why you don't use `numpy` for this...

Comment: I wouldn't use the same loop variable name in a double list comprehension (definition of `result`)

Comment: I don't see any code here which would provide different results between Python 2 and Python 3.  Please post sample input which reproduces the issue.

Comment: Hey guys this is for the google foobar challenge and they use python 2.7.6 sandbox. No numpy is allowed and I can't debug while submitting the solution. :/

Comment: In Python 2, list-comprehensions have "leaky scope".  so don't re-use `i`

Comment: Cannot reproduce in version 2.7.13 multiplying a 2x3 with 3x1 or 3x4